# Define code sections in sql managment studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a very long script in sql. I'm working with SSMS 2012 and sql servr 2012.

The sturctre is somewhere like this:

```
--Loans_Group 
--2013
create view Loans_2013
(
select * from X where yr=2013
)
go

--2014
create view Loans_2014
(
select * from X where yr=2014
)
go
--2015
create view Loans_2015
(
select * from X where yr=2015
)
go
--2016
create view Loans_2016
(
select * from X where yr=2016
)
go
--2017
create view Loans_2017
(
select * from X where yr=2017
)
go


--Credit scoring Group 

--2013
create view CS
(
select * from Y where yr=2013
)
go

--2014
create view CS where yr=2014
(
select * from Y
)
go


--2015
create view CS
(
select * from Y where yr=2015
)
go


--2016
create view CS where yr=2016
(
select * from Y
)
go


--2017
create view CS where yr=2017
(
select * from Y
)
go


create view Loans_Join as (
select * from Loans_2013
union
select * from Loans_2014
union
select * from Loans_2015
union
select * from Loans_2016
union
select * from Loans_2017
)
select * into Loans_Join_table from Loans_Join  

create view CS_Join as (
select * from  CS_2013
union
select * from  CS_2014
union
select * from  CS_2015
union
select * from  CS_2016
union
select * from  CS_2017
)
select * into CS_Join_table from CS_Join  


create view FlatFile as (

select * from Loans_Join
left join CS_Join on Loans_Join.Cust = CS_Join.Cust

)
```

Now, Suppose I would like to create a Analysis Table only for 2014-2015. In order to that I will need to comment all the parts of code of the other years... including those parts in the views where I am union-ing all the views from all the years - Loans_Join and CS_Join.
In my real code there are something like 20 groups beside Loans and CS. 
There is a reason why in order to create my Analysis Table I'm dividing it to parts of years and not using parameters. It's a little long for me here to get into those reasons. 
I'm asking for an easy way I can set code sections and comment them when I execute the query. 
Something like this:

set code sections = (2013,2014,2015,2016,2017)
comment Code_Sections = (2014,2015)
and the press the F5 key.. Is someone know an option like that?

Comment: Can you explain what problem you're attempting to solve by creating views like this? I don't see what the advantage is here over having proper indexes on your tables and querying them directly. Also, you should know that nested views (like you have here) can lead to major performance issues as the optimizer can't do a proper cardinality estimate once you've nested several layers deep, and that will result in a poor execution plan.